# How to insert to a HashSet<i32> which is the value of HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a `HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>>`, and I want to call `insert` to the value `HashSet<i32>` given key of the `HashMap`. Here is my attempt:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let map: HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, HashSet::new());
    map.entry(1).insert(1);
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

and the compiler says:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `insert` found for enum `std::collections::hash_map::Entry` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |     map.entry(1).insert(1);
  |                  ^^^^^^ help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `insert_entry`
```

Why can not method `entry` used to change `HashMap`'s value? Can anyone fix this for me?

Comment: Because this is not a value, this is an entry.

Comment: So how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map.entry(1)` returns an [Entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) not the value in the map (to cover the case where the key is not found). In your case, you can merge the two map lines together

```
let map: HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>> = HashMap::new();
// HashSet implements Default so `or_default()` will
// insert an empty set and return a mutable reference to it.
map.entry(1).or_default().insert(1);
println!("{:?}", map);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, HashSet::new());
    let iter = map.entry(1).or_insert(HashSet::new());
    iter.insert(1);
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).